Problem with simultaneously listening to audio and recording it to a file
I have this command that does not play sound and does not record a file (it creates, but the file length is 0 bytes). It is important that I want to save audio to wav from the src0 source.
gst-launch-1.0 audiomixer name=mixer udpsrc name=src0 uri=udp://127.0.0.1:3000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=audio,payload=8,clock-rate=8000,encoding-name=PCMA" ! tee name=app ! queue ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! mixer.sink_0 udpsrc name=src1 uri=udp://127.0.0.1:3010 caps="application/x-rtp,media=audio,payload=8,clock-rate=8000,encoding-name=PCMA" ! queue ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! mixer.sink_1 mixer. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audiorate ! volume name=vol volume=10.0 !audiopanorama name=panorama panorama=0 ! autoaudiosink name=audio_sink app. ! queue ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! wavenc name=wv ! filesink name=filesink location=input.wav

However, if I don't use "tee", then each command separately works:
I hear and receive sound:
gst-launch-1.0 audiomixer name=mixer udpsrc name=src0 uri=udp://127.0.0.1:3000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=audio,payload=8,clock-rate=8000,encoding-name=PCMA" ! queue ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! mixer.sink_0 udpsrc name=src1 uri=udp://127.0.0.1:3010 caps="application/x-rtp,media=audio,payload=8,clock-rate=8000,encoding-name=PCMA" ! queue ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! mixer.sink_1 mixer. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audiorate ! volume name=vol volume=10.0 ! audiopanorama name=panorama panorama=0 ! autoaudiosink name=audio_sink

I record a correct wav file with a non-zero length, which I can then listen to:
gst-launch-1.0 audiomixer name=mixer udpsrc name=src0 uri=udp://127.0.0.1:3000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=audio,payload=8,clock-rate=8000,encoding-name=PCMA" ! queue ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! wavenc name=wv ! filesink name=filesink location=input.wav

What am I doing wrong in the first command because of which there is no sound or recording to the file?

Did you try gst-gtklaunch-1.0 instead of gst-launch-1.0?

For the first command, I think tee duplicates the incoming data stream and sends it to two separate branches, one branch goes to the app sink (intended for playback) and the other to the filesink (intended for recording). However, it seems the tee element might be interfering with the data flow for recording.

For some reason I can only use gst-launch-1.0.
About tee. I only use tee before the write part of the command. It seemed to me that this way I would split the flow only once. Perhaps I haven't fully understood how tee works?

gst pipelines are complex to me. i couldn't find problem of your pipeline, too. it need more time to test and debug. but you can find various debugging tools and contents about that. for example https://docs.amd.com/r/en-US/ug1449-multimedia/GStreamer-Debugging-Techniques-Using-GST-launch
